# Why display image in the GUI using while loop doesn't work?

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface

I have an assignment:

auto-display a series of pictures like the slideshow, the button is named as **btnAutoView**, and the function to display an image is called **displayImage(int index)**, index is order number of the picture, like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

The code is as following(counter is a global variable):

```
public void displayImage(int index)
{
    String[] imageList = getImages();
    String imageName =imageList[index];

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(filePath+'/'+imageName);
    Image image = icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(PhotoView.getWidth(),PhotoView.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    PhotoView.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
}

btnAutoView.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            counter=0;
            while(counter!=5){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                displayImage(counter++);
            }
        }
    });
```

when I click the button, the pictures should be showed one by one every 2 seconds. But it doesn't work,  I used **System.out.println(counter)** to check the **thread.sleep(2000)**, and it works fine, which means I cannot use **displayImage()** more than once.

So what's the problem here?

Comment: Yours is a very common question: Search on [Swing JFrame freezing](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+jframe+freezing), then read [Lesson: Concurrency and Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Then you'll see why your Thread.sleep is essentially freezing your GUI. Use a Swing Timer instead (Google the tutorial).

Comment: Actually, [these are better duplicate questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+displaying+images+in+a+loop). Again, use that Swing Timer.

Comment: Seriously, does anybody know how to use Google or the search functionality of SO?!  There are more duplicate questions been asked then actual new ones these days :(